# Bash foreach on cronjob

Tags: bash, loops, unix, foreach, cron

I am trying to create a "watch" folder where I will be able to copy files 2 sets of files with the same name, but different file extensions. I have a program that need to reference both files, but since they have the same name, only differing by extension I figure I might be able to do something like this with  a cron job

cronjob.sh:

```
#/bin/bash
ls *.txt > processlist.txt

for filename in 'cat processlist.txt'; do

/usr/local/bin/runcommand -input1=/home/user/process/$filename \
-input2=/home/user/process/strsub($filename, -4)_2.stl \
-output /home/user/process/done/strsub($filename, -4)_2.final;

echo "$filename finished processing"
done
```

but substr is a php command, not bash. What would be the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Konsolebox's solution was almost right, but the issue was that when you do ${filename:(-4)} it only returns the last 4 letters of the variable instead of trimming the last 4 off. When I did was change it to `${filename%.txt}` where the `%.txt` matches to the text I want to find and remove, and then just tagged .mp3 on at the end to change the extension.

His other suggestion of using this for loop also was much better than mine:

```
for filename in *.txt; do
```

The only other modification was putting the full command all on one line in the end. I divided it up here to make sure it was all easily visible.

Answer (score 1):

```
strsub($filename, -4)
```

in Bash is

```
${filename:(-4)}
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Your command can look like

```
/usr/local/bin/runcommand "-input1=/home/user/process/$filename" \
    "-input2=/home/user/process/${filename:(-4)}_2.stl" \
    "-output /home/user/process/done/${filename:(-4)}_2.final"
```

Note: Prefer quoting your arguments with variables around double-quotes to prevent word splitting and possible pathname expansion. This would be helpful to filenames with spaces.

It would also be better to directly pass your glob pattern as an argument to `for` to properly distribute tokens without getting split with word splitting.

```
for filename in *.txt; do
```